# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered to upgrade my open cart php version

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

array_splice($lines, ($line_id + 1) + $offset, 0, explode("\n", $add));

This line i facing error and i have upgrade version 7 to 7.3 now facing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in 7.1 this means that a variable passed is non numeric in an aritmetic operation you can cast the value To be sure. in your code i suspect **line_id** or **offset** you can use (int).